# cannot convert value of type 'Anyobject!' to expected argument type 'Int'

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to compare an Int with a JSON object but I encounter converting error. user_id is an Int and I also tried Int(sharedID) but it didn't work as well.  So how can I compare sharedID with user_id
Thank you.

```
 let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data:NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

            if error != nil
            {
                return
            }

            do {
                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                self.homeShareResults.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

                self.shareTableView.reloadData()

                if let parseJSON = json {

                    if let friends  = parseJSON["checkSharedImage"] as? [AnyObject]
                    {
                        for friendObj in friends
                        {

                            let sharedID = (friendObj["id"])

                            if sharedID == user_id {...}
```

Comment: Have you looked carefully to see if you have optionals mixed in with the results of your subscripting? Xcode can tell you the inferred types, and you're not doing implicit unwrapping I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a type cast any object.

```
if let sharedID = friendObj["id"] as? Int{
        if sharedID == user_id {...}
}
```

Or simply force cast as! Int